# Excel formula to make the first letter of each word a capital, without changing the remainder of the word

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to correct address entries in a workbook by ensuring all the terms use capital letters, however I can't use PROPER as it will also make the remainder of the terms lowercase.

For example, if someone enters **221B baker St, spring hill QLD, Australia**, I would like to change this to **221 Baker St, Spring Hill QLD, Australia**.

If I use the PROPER function for this, **QLD** is changed to **Qld**, which is incorrect.

So far I have written a formula to check if a cell is already in uppercase, and if it is, then return that cell value as it is. However, if the cell is not in uppercase, then use the PROPER function on it.

```
=IF(EXACT(UPPER(A1),A1),A1,PROPER(A1))
```

I would like to use this formula, however apply it to each word individually rather than the entire cell. I am not able to use VBA for this.

Update: I have managed to this this, however the formula is not very elegant:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," a"," A")," b"," B")," c"," C")," d"," D")," e"," E")," f"," F")," g"," G")," h"," H")," j"," J")," k"," K")," l"," L")," m"," M")," n"," N")," o"," O")," p"," P")," q"," Q")," r"," R")," s"," S")," t"," T")," u"," U")," v"," V")," w"," W")," x"," X")," y"," Y")," z"," Z"),", a",", A"),", b",", B"),", C",", C"),", d",", D"),", e",", E"),", f",", F"),", g",", G"),", h",", H"),", j",", J"),", k",", K"),", l",", L"),", m",", M"),", n",", N"),", o",", O"),", p",", P"),", q",", Q"),", r",", R"),", s",", S"),", t",", T"),", u",", U"),", v",", V"),", w",", W"),", x",", X"),", y",", Y"),", z",", Z")
```

Comment: Is the address all in one cell or are you concatenating it?

Comment: All in one cell

Comment: Is there a reason the address can't be split? I've worked with many spreadsheets containing addresses over the years and if you ever want to sort or filter by Suburb or State for example, you will have a challenge with that setup.

Comment: You don't need to substitute `", @"`, they are already relaced by the `" @"`.  So you can halve that formula

Comment: FYI If that's the solution you've settled on, you should post it as an Answer, rather than editing it into your Q

Comment: Can you use the power query or dax function?

Comment: You can easily solve this in Power Query or VBA.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky without VBA.

You basically need to

1. split the string into words
2. replace the first character of each word with its upper case version
3. reassemble the sentence

Step 1 can be achieved with `FilterXML`, using space as the delimiter (Note, this assumes every word is seperated with at least a space, and possibly other characters too)

```
=FILTERXML("<b><a>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</a><a>")&"</a></b>","//a")
```

Step 2 uses `Replace`, `Upper` and `Left` to process the first character of each word

```
=REPLACE(B1#,1,1,UPPER(LEFT(B1#,1)))
```

Step 3 uses `TEXTJOIN` to reassemble the sentance

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,C1#)
```

[image]

Putting it all together is a single formula

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE,REPLACE(FILTERXML("<b><a>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</a><a>")&"</a></b>","//a"),1,1,UPPER(LEFT(FILTERXML("<b><a>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</a><a>")&"</a></b>","//a"),1))))
```

`TEXTJOIN` was added in version 2017.  `FILETERXML` in version 2013

To make it work in version >= 2013 and < 2017, use `CONCAT` instead of `TEXTJOIN`, plus a few tweeks to make it work.

```
=TRIM(CONCAT(REPLACE(FILTERXML("<b><a>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</a><a>")&"</a></b>","//a"),1,1," "&UPPER(LEFT(FILTERXML("<b><a>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</a><a>")&"</a></b>","//a"),1)))))
```

Comment: It seems I don't have the TEXTJOIN function in my version (Office 2016). Is that something I can create?

Comment: It was added in a later version of Excel.  Using `CONCAT` is an alternative, with a bit of extra work

Comment: Sorry, it also seems I don't have the FILTERXML option either.

Comment: Note the step by step example uses Dynamic Arrays feature addre to Excel 365, so won't work for you.  The combined version should (I think) but I can't text on the old version

Comment: According to Google, FILTERXML was added in V2013.  May be time for an upgrade.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It is in there, it is CONCAT that isn't. I have used CONCATENATE instead, however it is removing all the text after the first space.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought `CONCAT` was introduce in V2016. `CONCATENATE` really won't do here, it can't handle arrays, which is required for this technique to work

Answer (score 1):

Try this longer formula of which doesnot required TEXTJOIN or CONCAT function,

In `B1`, enter formula :

```
=REPLACE(A1,1,MATCH(2,INDEX(1/(CODE(MID(LEFT(A1,LOOKUP(99,FIND(" ",A1,ROW($1:$99)))),ROW($1:$99),1))>96),0)),PROPER(LEFT(A1,MATCH(2,INDEX(1/(CODE(MID(LEFT(A1,LOOKUP(99,FIND(" ",A1,ROW($1:$99)))),ROW($1:$99),1))>96),0)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this wouldn't work if the original was `221B baker St, spring hill QLD, australia` and would leave `australia` as is.

Answer (score -1):

I split your address into its components, using the comma as a element separator. This may not work on all shapes of addresses you get but the formulas below may serve as a base for a better solution yet to be worked out.

1. A2 = 221B baker St, spring hill QLD, Australia
2. B2 =IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2)-1)),A2)
3. C2 =MID(LEFT(A2,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","^",2))-1),FIND(",",A2)+1,100)
4. D2 =TRIM(LEFT(C2,LEN(C2)-LEN(E2)))
5. E2 =TRIM(MID(C2,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(C2," ","^",LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2, " ", ""))))+1,100))
6. F2 =TRIM(MID(A2,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","^",2))+1,100))

=PROPER(B2) & ", " & PROPER(D2) & " " & UPPER(E2) & ", " &  PROPER(F2)
returns the desired result.